# \$ doesn't seem to be working when I set PS1 in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, prompt

I'm trying to understand customising the terminal on my mac. I've been playing around with changing the PS1 variable and I've found that \$ doesn't seem to work like the other escape characters. For example, below is a snippet from my terminal.

```
$PS1="\w\$"
~$echo $PS1
\w$
```

My question is, when I type `echo $PS1` why does it display `\w$` and not `\w\$` ? and with PS1 set as above, if I was running the terminal as a superuser, would I see $ or #?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, which is the default terminal shell on OSX, double quoted strings support some special characters such as `\` and `$`.  In the expression `"\w\$"`, `\$` is interpreted as an escaped literal for the character `$`.

If you want `$PS1` to contain the string `\w\$`, use single quotes:

```
PS1='\w\$'
```

Or, with double quotes, use `\\` for backslash and `\$` for the dollar sign:

```
PS1="\\w\\\$"
```

When `$PS1` is set to `\w$`, the prompt will always end with a `$`, even as root.  When `$PS1` is set to `\w\$`, the prompt will end with a `#` if the effective uid is 0, otherwise `$`.

Comment: This explanation is correct, but a little confusing.  To clarify, when you type `$PS1="\w\$"` and press enter, bash is evaluating the line and instantly changes the `\$` to `$`.  Then it is saved to the variable PS1.  Thus, if you escape the backslash with another backslash, it will be sent to the variable verbatim.  So `$PS1="\w\\$"` will then show `\w\$` when you echo it.  The reason `\w` works is because \w isn't an escape sequence.